# Excel VBA Function will not work with an argument as a Range

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, range, return-value

I have written a fairly simple VBA function that I want to use in my worksheet and others that are linked to the macro worksheet. I am allowing the user to input a value OR a range (basically a cell reference) as the argument.

```
Public Function TSTT(arg As Range) As Single
    Dim a25 As Variant
    a25 = 522.6 - (arg / 155.2867)

    TSTT= a25
End Function
```

The problem is when I use Range as the type (as above) and the user inputs a value in the formula I get a #VALUE as the return.

If I declare the argument as a single then it works if the user inputs a value or a cell reference.

Finally if I declare the argument as a Variant it also works with both types of input.

To allow both types of inputs should I use the Variant or the expected type?

Comment: You are not returning TSTT anywhere in the function!

Comment: yeah sorry that last line was meant to return the result. fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the argument in the function header, you can test what the user has given you.  You can actually test what the user has given you:

```
Function foo(r) As String
    If TypeOf r Is Range Then
      v = r.Value
    Else
        v = r
    End If
    '
    '   more stuff
    '
End Function
```

Comment: Ahhh that's what I was thinking that there had to be a way to do that. Thanks for putting me on the right path. Is this how MS structures their functions because on many of theirs you can use either a range or a value.